# How we can set or change the background of Swipe layout or Recycle view like Whatsapp chat

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create same UI as whatsapp chat.Here you can see whatsapp has background image:

[image: background]

Now this is my app in which I have a relative layout that contains swipe layout (`androidx.swiperefreshlayout`) in which it has recycle view. This is my app with normal color background:

[image: no background]

I just want to set an image in the background same as WhatsApp. In order to achieve this what should I do?

Comment: Well you can visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-random-background-for-recyclerview-in-android and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330119/background-image-on-the-recyclerviews-gridlayout-views-android

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put it in the XML like this?

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lst_main"
        android:background="@drawable/name_of_your_background"
        />
```